# UNet image infilling with both image and categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mlp, unet-neural-network

I'm working on a project where I have both image data and numeric categorical data for each image. The categorical data is not pixel-dependent, it's like a label. So one data entry might look like: [ $image$, $number$, $number$ ]. The goal is to perform image infilling on the images, for which I am now using a UNet architecture in PyTorch based on: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41561-020-0582-5. For training, I am artificially masking parts of the input image and then letting the model figure out how to fill in the gaps again.

What I would like to do is to improve the accuracy of the infilling model by incorporating the categorical data, which I believe contains information that could help 'steer' the model to a correct infilled image output, i.e. the categorical data and image data are correlated. To illustrate with an arbitrary example, let's say the image data contains pictures of faces and the categorical data contains the person's age and gender, which could help the model to include more or less wrinkles and makeup in the infilled image.

I was wondering if anyone here has any experience with this, or ideas on how best to accomplish this.

My efforts so far over the last month:

- I have tried encoding the categorical data as constant-valued matrices and using these as extra input channels next to the image data. This has so far not improved the model accuracy. I could try changing the encoding method, like switching to one-hot-encoding, but the consensus online seems to be that this method of mixing data as input channels will likely not yield good results.
- All results I found online that use CNNs with mixed input data are being used for image categorization, i.e. an architecture which does not have an encoder/decoder structure like UNet, and these results are thus of limited use to me.
- Many of these CNN image categorization examples suggest 'preprocessing' the image data in an extra CNN branch and the categorical data in a separate MLP branch, concatenating the two outputs, and then feeding the combined result into the actual model. I am unsure however how I could apply this to a UNet, and what I would have to do to the output layer in order to transform the output data back to an image that I can compare to the ground truth for training.